# Checkbox filed not filtering form acf fields

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, advanced-custom-fields, meta

I have used ACF checkbox fields. Now I want to filter query is this checkbox field. Then I am trying to search from the front end. But it's not showing any result. Field meta_key is `cotf`.
[acf fields screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp0oG.png)

[acf fields screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwfLh.png)

```
<form action="" id="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="ap_features[]" value="air_conditioning">
<input type="checkbox" name="ap_features[]" value="washer_connections">
<input type="checkbox" name="ap_features[]" value="refrigerator">
<input  class="btn btn-lg  btn-success" type='submit' id="" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $afeatures = $_POST['ap_features'];
        $args = array(  
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'apartment',
            'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'cotf',
                    'value' => array($afeatures),
                    'compare'   => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

I have also trying this code but its not working:

```
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach ($_POST['ap_features'] as $value) {
      $meta_query[] = array(
      'key' => 'cotf',
      'value' => '"'.$value.'"',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    }
    $args = array(
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'restaurant',
      'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $args = array(  
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'apartment',            
    );
    $afeatures = $_POST['ap_features'];

    if(is_array($afeatures)){
        $afeaturesArr = implode(",",$afeatures);

        $args['meta_query']= array(
        'relation'=>array('AND',
            array(
            'key'       => 'cotf',
            'value' => explode(",",$afeaturesArr),
            'compare'   => 'IN'
            )            
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vel but its showing this error `Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\verde\wp-includes\class-wp-meta-query.php on line 131`

Comment: `Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\verde\wp-includes\class-wp-meta-query.php on line 131`

Comment: I didnt use this function `strtoupper()` in my code. check your code

Comment: print this value and check. `$_POST['ap_features']`. it is a string or array?

Comment: print_r result `Array ( [0] => business_center [1] => clubhouse )`

Comment: Hi @vel, Could you please answer this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849910/marge-wordpress-query-argument-filter

Comment: Thanks. Please check